# Python interactive graphs library

Tags: python, user-interface, graph

I'm writing a software in Python for graphs creation and visualization. I can't find a graphic library to use (in addition to PyQt) to display a graph (different types of nodes with edges) and let the user modify it by adding and deleting nodes and edges. The idea is to manage graphs in a similar way to Dia, for example.

Comment: I also have a spreadsheet type of dataset and want use Python to generate column-pair cross-plots. Each cross-plot should come in a separate window and be customizable by a user in terms of symbols, axes, etc. Besides user may want to save the current graph settings and load/apply them later. Is there a Python library to generate this kind of plots?